# Как добавить в этом коде удаление и добавление записей?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
// Описать класс "Студенческая группа". Необходимо создать следующие методы класса:
// 1. работа с переменным числом студентов;
// 2. поиск студента по какому-либо признаку (например, по фамилии, дате рождения или номеру телефона);
// 3. добавление и удаление записей;
// 4. сортировка по разным полям.
// Продемонстрировать работу с этим классом. Обязательно наличие меню, через которое можно проверить работу всех методов класса.
namespace MyProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" ==================== Группа ЭВТ-18-1б ==================== ");
            string u;
            List<string> FIO = new List<string>();
            FIO.Add(" Вавилонов А.А. ");
            FIO.Add(" Антонов К.Д.   ");
            FIO.Add(" Алабаев С.А.   ");
            FIO.Add(" Петренко П.П.  ");


            foreach (string n in FIO)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" ФИО: {0}", n);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\t");

            List<string> Birthday = new List<string>();
            Birthday.Add(" 09.02.2000 ");
            Birthday.Add(" 12.12.1996 ");
            Birthday.Add(" 11.05.1998 ");
            Birthday.Add(" 20.08.1999 ");

            foreach (string b in Birthday)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" День Рождения: {0}", b);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\t");

            List<byte> Age = new List<byte>();
            Age.Add(19);
            Age.Add(22);
            Age.Add(10);
            Age.Add(25);

            foreach (byte a in Age)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Возраст: {0}",a);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\t");

            List<string> Phone = new List<string>();
            Phone.Add(" 88005553551 ");
            Phone.Add(" 89351358253 ");
            Phone.Add(" 86434235625 ");
            Phone.Add(" 87242146821 ");

            foreach (string p in Phone)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Номер телефона: {0}", p);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: конкретнее пожалуйста, что хотите добавить куда и когда. Ну и с удалением та же исторя. Из того что я вижу - создать класс `Person` у которого будет ФИО, телефон, день рождение, и реализовать в этом классе методы `add` и `remove`

Comment: а вы удалять и обновлять информацию о студенте по какому полю будете ? Ну например в БД для этого `id` вводиться

Comment: В самой задаче просто мне было дано что попробовать реализовать её с помощью листов

Comment: У меня получилось написать только вот что представлено, а как реализовать добавление или удаление студентов не знаю ну и чтобы получается уже выводился измененный список

Comment: Не могли бы вы помочь с реализацией данного задания с помощью листов? Ну или помочь с добавлением и удалением?

Answer (score -1):

```
//Rextester.Program.Main is the entry point for your code. Don't change it.
//Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Students studentsList = new Students(new List<Student>(){
                new Student(1,"Вася Я.Я.",DateTime.Parse("10.10.1995"),"+380678838340"),
                new Student(2,"Гася Я.Я.",DateTime.Parse("10.10.1995"),"+380678838340"),
                new Student(3,"Дася Я.Я.",DateTime.Parse("10.10.1995"),"+380678838340"),
            });

            studentsList.Display();
            Console.Write("\n\n");


            studentsList.Add(new Student(4,"Пася Я.Я.",DateTime.Parse("10.10.1995"),"+380678838340"));

            studentsList.Display();
            Console.Write("\n\n");

            studentsList.Update(4, new Student(4,"Рася Я.Я.",DateTime.Parse("10.10.1996"),"+380000000000"));

            studentsList.Display();
            Console.Write("\n\n");

            studentsList.Remove(4);
            studentsList.Display();
        }

        public class Student
        {
            public string FIO;
            public DateTime Bithday;
            public string Phone;
            public int Id;
            public Student(int id,string FIO,DateTime bithday,string phone)
            {
                this.Id = id;
                this.FIO = FIO;
                this.Bithday = bithday;
                this.Phone = phone;
            }
        }

        public class Students
        {
            public List<Student> students;
            public Students(List<Student> students)
            {
                this.students = students;
            }

            public void Add(Student student)
            {
                students.Add(student);
            }

            public bool Update(int id, Student _student)
            {
                var student = students.FirstOrDefault(st => st.Id == id);
                if (student == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else 
                {
                    student.FIO = _student.FIO;
                    student.Bithday = _student.Bithday;
                    student.Phone = _student.Phone;
                    return true;
                }

            }

            public void Remove(int id)
            {
                for (int i = 0 ; i < students.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (students[i].Id == id)
                    {
                        students.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }
            }

            public void Display()
            {
                students.ForEach(st => Console.Write(st.FIO + "  " + st.Bithday + "   " + st.Phone + "\n"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @kLuS [тут](https://rextester.com/FDE35487) можно проверить

Comment: Если ставите минус, пожалуйста пишите причину...

Comment: Я поставил минус за то что вы по сути выполняете чужую домашку, **даже не комментируя что и как вы сделали** - поощряете таким образом использование ruSO не как базы знаний, а как "бесплатного фриланса".

Comment: @Kromster вопрос: `Как добавить в этом коде удаление и добавление записей?` - вы полагаете нужно комментировать методы `Add` и `Remove`?... во всяком случае спасибо, что написали **причину** минуса

Comment: Полагаю, что раз у ТС возник такой вопрос, то написание этих методов для ТС проблематично, и нужно их прокомментировать, "разжевать". Это при условии, что мы полагаем добросовестность ТС..